# Current workbook affect other workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make a button in workbook1 .When you click the button , you can select multiple files with workbook2,workbook3.. (all excel files with xlsx, only the workbook1 is xlsm). After you choose the excel workbook files, the function will add a column name "format" and the "No" Value in cells to match the right rows. Is this can accomplish with using VBA? Because I google it and show me enough copy other workbook data to current book and change it in current workbook.

And I have a error of this programme. The output have a format but add more than one column.

[image]

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Call Module1.AddWISFormat
   MsgBox "Add format successful"
End Sub
```

```
Sub AddWISFormat()

NForm = Application _
        .GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls", Title:="Select File To Be Opened(Data File)", MultiSelect:=True)
        
      If IsArray(NForm) Then  'ensure validity
        Dim TotalNumOfRecord As Integer
        TotalNumOfRecord = 1
        
        Dim FormIndex As Integer
        FormIndex = 1
        For Each Form In NForm
        
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=Form  'open source file
            nFormName = ActiveWorkbook.Name  'Store the filename
            
            Set FileData = ActiveSheet.UsedRange 'copy data from source file
            Dim FileRows As Integer
            Dim FileCols As Integer
            
            FileRows = FileData.Rows.Count
            FileCols = FileData.Columns.Count
            'ThisWorkbook.Activate   'back to the originalworkbook
            
            For RowIndex = 1 To FileRows
                Dim ColumnBValue As Double
                Debug.Print (ColumnBValue)
                ColumnBValue = FileData.Cells(RowIndex, 2)
                If (IsNumeric(ColumnBValue)) Then   'for new format
                    'If (ColumnAValue = dd / mm / yyyy) Then
                        With Worksheets("Sheet1")
                            .Range("C4").EntireColumn.Insert
                            .Range("C4").Value = "Format"
                            .Cells(RowIndex, 3).Value = "No"
                        End With
                    'End If
                End If
            Next
            
            Workbooks(nFormName).Activate  'activate source file
            Workbooks(nFormName).Close SaveChanges:=True 'close source file
            
            FormIndex = FormIndex + 1
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "No files were selected."
        End
    End If
        
End Sub
```

| Testing Report |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Report number |  |  |
| Date | Name | address |
| 1/1/2022 | Andy | Tuen mun |
| 1/1/2022 | Mandy | Tsuen Wan |
| 2/1/2022 | Creamy | Lai Chi Kok |
| 2/1/2022 | Betty | Lai Chi Kok |
| Total : 4 |  |  |
| Date | Name | address |
| 3/1/2022 | Jenny | Tsing Yi |
| 3/1/2022 | Ellas | Stanley |
| 4/1/2022 | Dennis | Mong Kok |
| 5/2/2022 | Doris | Tsim Sha Tsui |
| 5/2/2022 | Ben | Prince Edward |
| Total : 5 |  |  |
| Total：９ |  |  |
| ＊Ｅｎｄ Ｒｅｐｏｒｔ＊ |  |  |

Comment: It certainly can accomplish with using VBA, but which parts do you don't know? search workbook ? add column or match??

Comment: umm.. I think I am no idea to match because I need to add the format to the right position(As you can see the picture ).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community  I am sorry to upload last the code

Answer (score -1):

Let say if you find name Andy in sheet , insert a format column and fill "No"

You do as following code:

```
Public Sub Insert()

Sheets(1).Range("C1").EntireColumn.Insert
Sheets(1).Cells(1, 3) = "format"

MaxRow = Sheets(1).Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 1 To MaxRow
  
If Sheets(1).Cells(x, 2) = "Andy" Then
Sheets(1).Cells(x, 3).Value = "No"
End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: But I want to find all name and set value "No" in each rows including the name. The reason is the other informaton of account in rows and I need to exclude them to get the right rows with name and add a colume value "No".